# How can you logout with Realm javascript?

Tags: react-native, realm

I'm using the Realm self hosted platform for javascript for a react native App.  The login code works fine, as show below...

```
Realm.Sync.User.login('http://0.0.0.0:9080', creds)
.then(result => resolve(result))
.catch(error => reject(error))
...
```

However, when I try to logout, I get an error that says Realm.Sync.User.logout is not a function.   Here is the logout code...

```
logout = () => {
    Realm.Sync.User.logout()
}
```

I've gone through the docs a few times, but it seems this function simply doesn't exist.  https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/api/Realm.Sync.User.html

I'm using realm 2.18.0.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are trying to use `logout` as a static method, but it is an instance method. You need to store a reference to your logged in `User` instance and call `logout` on that instance.

```
Realm.Sync.User.login('http://0.0.0.0:9080', creds)
.then(user => resolve(user))
.catch(error => reject(error))
...
```

Make sure that you define `user` to be in scope for `logout` and also make sure that you only call `logout` once `login` is resolved.

```
logout = () => {
    user.logout()
}
```